# Bounded function in a interval $(a, b)$: must be monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, monotone-functions

Given $a, b \in\mathbb R$ with $−∞ < a \leqslant b < ∞$, every monotonic function in $\mathbb{R}^{[a,b]}$ $(f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$) is bounded.

Do we need the "monotonic" part there? Isn't every function that belongs to an interval whose domain is defined in that way bounded?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You do not need it if $f$ is continuous. Btw: in the title you have an open interval $(a,b)$ and in the question $[a,b]$ is closed.

Comment: Question title is misleading.

Comment: It's quite obvious that every monotone function $f$ is bounded on a closed interval. We have $\min(f(a), f(b)) \leq f(x) \leq \max(f(a), f(b)) $ for all $x\in[a, b] $ if $f$ is monotone. But just having a bounded domain does not mean the function is bounded. The bounded nature of a function is about the bounded nature of its range and not its domain.

Comment: For example $\arctan x$ is bounded even though it's domain $\mathbb{R} $ is unbounded. The case of an unbounded function on a bounded domain is already provided in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take, for instance$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x=0\\\frac1x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$

Comment: This shows that "monotonic" is needed.

Comment: What I wrote is an answer to the question “Isn't every function that belongs to an interval whose domain is defined in that way bounded?”